# How can I force the user to save an excel file in excel?

Tags: c#, excel, process

I am create an .xls file programatically and opening it in excel

for example:

```
Process.Start("c:/blabla.xls");
```

I am deleting the file when excel is closed, so I would like to prompt the user if he wants to save the file when excel before it is closed, and ideally make him save it to a new location.

I'm hoping there is an argument I can feed to excel during the Process.Start

Comment: Here's a list of the command-line switches supported by Excel: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of opening Excel with an Excel file (`.xls`), you could open Excel with a Excel template (`.xlt`). This should open a new, unnamed file in Excel, using your xlt as the template. Since the file is unnamed, the user will be prompted to choose a location and file name if he made any changes.

(I'm not sure if renaming the file suffices; you might have to *save the file as a template*.)

**EDIT**: In fact, there is a command-line switch lets you do exactly that (open a normal Excel file as a template):

```
excel.exe /t C:\blabla.xls
```

Comment: The template partially solves my problem. It now saves to a new location, that is good. But if the user doesn't do any changes to excel file, excel doesn't prompt to save. Is there a way to override that?

Comment: @Marcom: I don't know a way to override that. Another option would be to force the user to choose a storage location *before* opening the file: (1) Show a Save File Dialog (using the System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog class), (2) save the file to that location, (3) open the file with Excel (and don't delete it afterwards).

Answer (score 2):

Handle the BeforeClosed event.

This is assuming you are using Excel automation. Which, after reading your question again it appears you are not.

http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip78.htm

Comment: I am using xlsio but at this stage the workbook is closed and saved, and I launch excel independently not to block my application.